# Stomp SockJS Error

Tags: spring, websocket, jackson, stomp, sockjs

My app works fine when sockjs is using the websocket protocol. But when it falls back from websockets to XHR Streaming, I am getting an error in the server.

```
22:27:13,340||ERROR|XhrReceivingTransportHandler:|Failed to read message
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
    at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@6aded705; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164) ~[jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3036) ~[jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2978) ~[jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2144) ~[jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.frame.Jackson2SockJsMessageCodec.decodeInputStream(Jackson2SockJsMessageCodec.java:67) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.XhrReceivingTransportHandler.readMessages(XhrReceivingTransportHandler.java:41) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Any help is much appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem. This was happening since we were using Apache Httpd as a proxy server. Switched apache to nginx and the problem got resolved.